# i installed ubuntu 12.4 version both wifi and lan are not working

Tags: ethernet, intel-wireless

May laptop is Lenovo g580 which is now dual booting Windows 7 & Ubuntu.

In Ubuntu, the WiFi symbol is present at the top but there's no list of active WiFi networks. I tried LAN but its also not detectable.

Please help me. This is the first time I installed Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please open a terminal and paste here the output of this command: `lshw -c network`. Please use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ or similar services if you are unable to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try **left** clicking on the Wi-Fi icon instead of right-click. Then you should see a list of networks. If that doesn't work, try rebooting.